# Simple plot bug in Octave 4.2.1

Tags: image, octave

I want to update to a newer version of Octave and I am testing Octave 4.2.1 (64bit on Windows10). I get a strange bug with this simple "imagesc" and marker with "plot" with this code:

```
figure;
imagesc(rand(10));
hold on;
plot(2,5, 'r+', 'Linewidth',10);
```

First there is the output of this whole script with a strange display in the image and a strange text output in the console:

[image: A]

If I remove the "plot" line, the strange stuff disappears and I only get the random matrix as expected:

[image: B]

If I use a recent MATLAB version it is displayed correctly.

[image: C]

Comment: Using Octave 4.2.1 under Ubuntu (64bit) it works flawless with the default qt graphics toolkit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching the bug directly on https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/ I found it in https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=detailitem&item_id=50620. It is to be fixed (at least for the toolkit gnuplot) in the next minor version 4.2.2 that seems to be released soon.

Comment: Octave 4.2.2 has been released few days ago and the bug is fixed now for all the three toolkits gnuplot, fltk and qt.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug when using the `gnuplot` graphics toolkit - I can reproduce the issue.

When using the `fltk` graphics toolkit, it works fine:

[image]

When using the `qt` graphics toolkit, it also works but I get lots of warning messages:

```
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: called from
    newplot at line 208 column 5
    image at line 110 column 11
    imagesc at line 98 column 12
>> hold on;
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: called from
    hold at line 59 column 3
>> plot(2,5, 'r+', 'Linewidth',10);warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object

>> warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object

>> warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
warning: opengl_renderer: Error 1280 occurred drawing 'text' object
```

[image]

I would suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: I can't see any problems using qt on the default branch, which version are you using?

Comment: I use 4.2.1 on Windows, but those warnings may be due to the renderer or my particular graphics card?